# optimizing a nested dictionary result

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

in my code I want to make a nested dictionary from a sentence. in my dictionary I have a key which is a word of the sentence and it's value is a dictionary that tells me its similarity with other words of the sentence using fuzzy matching. the point is, if we consider my sentence like

> my_text = "Have you ever wanted" and my output as

> {'Have': {'you': 0, 'ever': 50, 'wanted': 50}, 'you': {'Have': 0, 'ever': 0, 'wanted': 0}, 'ever': {'Have': 57, 'you': 0, 'wanted': 33}, 'wanted': {'Have': 50, 'you': 0, 'ever': 33}}

I want to remove repetitive combinations like have ever and ever have for example and I do not know how! this is my code :
'''

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

my_text = "Have you ever wanted"

str_list = my_text.split()

job_dict = {
    k: {}
    for k in str_list
}
# new_lst = []
for key in job_dict.keys():
    job_dict[key] = {}
    for key2 in job_dict.keys():
        #print(key, key2)
        if key == key2:
            continue

        job_dict[key][key2] = fuzz.partial_ratio(key, key2)

print(job_dict)
```

'''

Comment: The examples you gave (have/ever and ever/have) have different values/weights (50 and 57). What identifies a removable candidate?

Comment: @jarmod I can fix that by using token_sort_ratio instead of partial_ratio in my code. so they will have equal values and one of must be deleted

Comment: By the way, what are you trying to achieve here? What is the value of calculating how similar one word in a given sentence is to another word in the same sentence?

Comment: @jarmord first of all I want to know how can I do this, second of all  if this code works it wont be applied on a sentence , it will be applied on a field of my mongodb collection that has lots of strings. it is a data cleaning task somehow and we need to know similarity of words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `itertools.combinations` to generate all combinations of any two words:

```
import itertools

combz = itertools.combinations(str_list, 2)
print(list(combz))
# [('Have', 'you'), ('Have', 'ever'), ('Have', 'wanted'), ('you', 'ever'), ('you', 'wanted'), ('ever', 'wanted')]
```

Then you can proceed with your code:

```
import itertools

my_text = "Have you ever wanted"
str_list = my_text.split()
job_dict = {}
func = lambda a,b: a+b  # For example purposes
for k1, k2 in itertools.combinations(str_list, 2):
    val = func(k1, k2)  # replace func with fuzz.partial
    if k1 in job_dict:
        job_dict[k1].update({k2: val})
    else:
        job_dict[k1] = {k2: val}

print(job_dict)
# {'Have': {'you': 'Haveyou', 'ever': 'Haveever', 'wanted': 'Havewanted'}, 'you': {'ever': 'youever', 'wanted': 'youwanted'}, 'ever': {'wanted': 'everwanted'}}
```

Comment: in my inner dictionary I have rates that I get from fuzzy. the point is , I do not want to calculate on combination two times since for a large data it will not be efficient example : I  want ratio of have and you only once in my output not two or three times

Comment: The answer doesn't have any repetitions.

Comment: As observed by @NagabhushanSN, the above structure has 0 repetitions ([find out more about combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination))

Comment: @NagabhushanSN 'Have': {'you': 0, 'ever': 50, 'wanted': 50}, 'you': {'Have': 0, 'ever': 0, 'wanted': 0}  here I have ,  HAVE and YOU then YOU and Have which are the same and I want it to be printed only once

Comment: @KIMIAGhassemzadeh This is *not* from the code above (Key `you`  doesn't contain `Have`). It seems you're new here, but if you do not bother to have a look at proposed solutions I'm afraid you're not going to find what you seek.